# Cannot find formatted drive to install Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, format

I am installing **ubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64** to my Win10 T460P ThinkPad but I have a little question at the final partition step. I wanna store it on my Linux(L:), which is about 55GB. But I cannot find it according to the tutorials online. They say the dev/sda is the right place but **my dev/sda is way too big and I cannot find the L**. Please help! Thanks!

[I formatted Linux(L) to store Ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DSHz.jpg)

[But i cannot find it, only the huge 1TB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHv2L.jpg)

Comment: `dev/sda` is the whole device (disk), the partitions are numbered (sda1, sda2,...). Drive letters are a windows thing. Have you partitioned anything yet?

Comment: @danzel  No cuz I wanna install it on the (L:) dive that I specialled for Linux system. The problem is I cannot find the (L:) (which is about 55GB) while choosing the `boot loader`. The `dev/std` now is `1TB`, way bigger that what I needed for just installing ubuntu.

Comment: @danzel   sorry I meant `dev/sda`

Comment: Comparing your screenshots, it looks like `/dev/sda` is the disk that is labelled `disk 0` in windows. But the partitions on your Ubuntu screenshot are different. If you proceed, all partitions on your 1TB drive will be deleted, and 4 new partitions will be created for Ubuntu. Which tutorial are you following? Which installation option did you choose in the installer?

Comment: @danzel yes I wanted dev/sda just be the (L:) specialized instead of the whole `disk 0` so I quit the installation to avoid what you said. I followed [link](https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/) [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation)to make a partition. The installation type is `Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10`.

Comment: `/dev/sda` is the whole `disk0`, always. The instructions on itsfoss tell you to free space using windows, and create partitions using the Ubuntu installer. You created one NTFS formatted partition (L:) using windows. You won't be able to install Ubuntu on an NTFS formatted partition. Make sure you follow the instructions carefully. And remember: `dev/sda` is the whole device, `dev/sda1`, `dev/sda2` etc. are partitions on that device. Don't get confused by windows' _drive_ term. In the context of HDDs/SSDs a windows _drive_ usually refers to a partition.

Comment: ...and make sure you choose the correct installation method (i.e. *something else*)